# Restart a separated process service when it's killed, without binding it to the app's main process

Tags: android, service

I would like to know if is there any way to restart a separated process service when it's killed (or crashes), without binding it to the app's main process (I want the service to remain running even when the app's main process is killed due to whatever reason).

Currently, that service is started by the system through the AndroidManifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.MySeparatedProcessService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="SeparatedProcessService"
    android:process=":separatedProcess"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.MySeparatedProcessService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The problem is that, when the system starts it, the following callback is **not** called:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

So I am not able to return `START_STICKY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of the broadcast receiver and pending intent to achieve this task.

here is a link which takes location update especially for oreo device.

[background-location-updates-android-o](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/background-location-updates-android-o)